# Porque o PyCharm não reconhece os módulos e classes criados pelo usuário?

Tags: python, pycharm

Olá, sou novo em python e comecei recentemente a trabalhar com a IDE PyCharm versão Community. Sobre a IDE, gostei bastante, uma das melhores IDE's que já utilizei. No entanto um problema que identifiquei nela é que ela não reconhece os módulos ou classes criados pelo usuário, talvez para que ela faça isso automaticamente precise ser feita alguma configuração antes que eu não tenha feito. Basicamente, eu crio o módulo ou classe e quando vou importar em outro arquivo, a IDE não reconhece, o nome do módulo fica sublinhado vermelho e quando eu tento escrever alguma função do módulo para chamá-la, a função não aparece no auto-complete. Mesmo não reconhecendo, os módulos/classes funcionam sem problemas, é preciso apenas digitar tudo manualmente sem erros que apesar da IDE não reconhecer, ela executa perfeitamente.
Gostaria de saber se alguém já teve problema similar antes e tenha resolvido. Preciso fazer alguma configuração para que a IDE reconheça automaticamente?
Agradeço de antemão a paciência de todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente isso é uma peculiaridade do PyCharm, você precisa informar para o PyChar que no diretório onde estão os teus códigos também existem módulos que podem ser importados.

Para fazer isso basta clicar com o botão direito em cima da pasta onde se encontram os teus códigos e ir até a opção "Mark Directory as" e clique na opção "Sources Root". Isso será o suficiente para você conseguir realizar os *imports* dos módulos que você criar.

Comment: Cara, você realmente solucionou o meu problema. Desculpe não ter visto sua resposta antes, passei um tempo sem acessar o Stackoverflow. Valeu mesmo.

Comment: De nada amigo, como pode ver eu também passei um tempo sem entrar aqui no Stackoverflow